# How do I change a decimal string to a hex formatted string?

Tags: python

How do I change a decimal string like `123456789` to a hex formatted string like this:

```
07:5B:CD:15
```

I have looked at the hex function, but it doesn't give me the above format.

**UPDATED**

I would also like -123456789 to be:

```
-07:5B:CD:15
```

rather than

```
-7:5B:CD:15
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s = '123456789'
a = '{:08X}'.format(int(s))
print ':'.join(a[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(a), 2))
```

prints

```
07:5B:CD:15
```

Comment: @eumiro Very nice! Thank you.

Comment: @eumiro One more thing, how would I get -123456789 to be -07:5B:CD:15?

Comment: @smithy - since `{:08X}` would replace the zero with a minus sign, I would use the `abs' value and then eventually put it in front of the resulting string.